# StreamProvider not rebuilding the widget tree when AsyncValue updates

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, riverpod

I am to listening firebase `AuthStateChanges` stream and provide the stream with `streamProvider` to change the view based on the stream value. And I did this:

```dart
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream get currentUser => _auth.authStateChanges();
}

final userStream = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) => AuthService().currentUser);

class AuthenticationWrapper extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final user = watch(userStream);
    print('AutenticationWrapper build method got called');
    return user.when(
      data: (data) {
        if (data?.uid == null) {
          print('I am currently Logged out ');
          return LogInPage();
        } else {
          print('I am logged in user');
          return HomePage();
        }
      },
      loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (e, s) => Text('Oops'),
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting to have LogIn page to be rendered when the `AsyncValue` of the `streamProvider` gets changed. The above code didn't work as expected; in fact, it prints the message but it doesn't return the Widget it is supposed to return. However, when I hot restart the app it will render the correct Widget based on the stream value.

Why doesn't the build method re-render when this: `final user = watch(userStream);` receives an update?

Comment: Can you please show how you are calling the login / logout functions of FirebaseAuth? With a slightly modified version of your code, I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AlexHartford as you might have guessed the problem was on login Widget, I manually called Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homePage'); this is code that cause this behavior. I've just figured that out... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should probably `watch(userStream.stream)` to be notified when the stream itself updates.  Haven't played much with StreamProvider though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: The way he is using the AsyncValue provided by StreamProvider is correct. You would have to use a StreamBuilder or similar widget to work with the raw stream as you suggested, which is fine, but unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! Learn something new every day!

Comment: The problem was on login Widget, I manually called Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homePage'); this is code that cause this behavior. I've just figured that out... thanks for your help.